# it appears an extra argument 'reply' in call at : reply: { ( success, error) in - what cand i do because i can not build the app in the simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, fingerprint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2UWn.png)

it appears an extra argument 'reply' in call at : reply: { ( success, error) in - what cand i do because i can not build the app in the simulator 
  let authenticationContext = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?

```
    if authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason:"Not let  somebody else", reply: { (success, error)   in

            if success {
                self.navigateToAuthenticatiedVC()
            } else{
                if let error = error as? NSError {
                    let message = self.errorMessageForErrorCode(errorCode: error.code)
                    self.showAlertViewAfterEvaluatingPolicyWithMessage(message: message)
                }
            }

        })
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [`evaluatePolicy(..., reply: ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy) on that line, not `canEvaluatePolicy`.

Comment: Thank you very very very much